# How to fix Safari 6 on Mountain Lion that doesn't show the full URL in the address bar unless I click it?

Tags: macos, safari

For instance, Ask Question page URL on this site is shown as `apple.stackexchange.com`, but when I focus on address bar, it becomes `apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`.

I tried resetting and restarting Safari, disabling extensions and dragging the default set into the toolbar but nothing helps.

Comment: Somehow it fixed by itself, no idea what has happened. But still would be nice to know what could cause this issue.

Comment: As far as I'm aware that's just how Safari 6 works

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't there all along? Safari 6 only shows the domain name in black, with the rest of the URL in light grey. Is it possible you just missed it? Maybe check the colour balance/contrast on your monitor.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that Safari 6 shows the rest of the URL in grey and I'm sure it wasn't there.

Answer (score 9):

I've found that logging out and back in is sufficient for fixing this. Still a pain, but takes slightly less time than restarting (which also recovers from the failure since it forces you as well as all other users to get logged out when the Mac shuts down).

Comment: A restart of my macbook and it fixed this issue when I came across the same problem.

Comment: Just happened to me (almost a year after your comment). The problem persists. Although the restart still fixes it (odd that simply quitting and reopening Safari doesn't fix it).

Comment: Just happened to me too, Safari 6.0.4, 2013-06-07.

Comment: Safari 6.0.5 still has the problem.

Comment: Logging out and back in didn't do the job for me.

Comment: A restart cured it.

Answer (score 3):

In Safari 8, there is a setting that makes the url visible.

> Safari >> Preferences >> Advanced >> Smart Search Field (show full website address)