# Information missing from Safari location bar

Tags: safari, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix Safari 6 on Mountain Lion that doesn’t show the full URL in the address bar unless I click it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61230/how-to-fix-safari-6-on-mountain-lion-that-doesnt-show-the-full-url-in-the-addre)

The address bar of Safari all of a sudden has stopped displaying full URLs, and is instead only displaying the hostname part of URLs. The full URL is only shown when I make the address bar active again as shown below.

images: [address bar](http://dckd.nl/~jeroen/stuff/loc.png) and 
[active bar](http://dckd.nl/~jeroen/stuff/loc-act.png)

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can restore the old behavior? I do have SafariStand installed, but it never did this before today.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you uninstall SafariStand and use GLIMS which is a better Safari enhancement app.

Comment: While Glims may be more powerful, it also rewrites Amazon and Ebay links in a way that I'm not comfortable with. I prefer the honest and totally free SafariStand.